# DRF update view with many to many field

Tags: api, django-models, django-rest-framework, django-views, many-to-many

Am trying to write update view,but got an error please help me to find the problem,thanks :)
At first  I have many to many field in my model.It is my model

```
    class Portfolio(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=50, unique=True, blank=False, null=True)
    market = models.ForeignKey(Market, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='market')
    investor = models.ForeignKey('accounts.User', on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='investor')
    assets = models.ManyToManyField(Assets, related_name='assets')

    

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name
```

After that I have a serializer for my view:

```
    class PortfolioSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):

    class Meta:
        model = Portfolio
        fields = ['name', 'market', 'investor', 'assets']
```

And it's my view:

```
    class PortfolioUpdateView(APIView):
    serializer_class = PortfolioSerializer

    def put(self, request, *args,):
        data = request.data
        portfo = Portfolio.objects.get(id=id)
        print(portfo)

        serilize = self.serializer_class(instance=request.user, data=request.POST)

        if serilize.is_valid():

            name = serilize.data['name']
            market = Market.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST.get('market', '')))
            assets = Assets.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST.get('assets', '')))

            Portfolio.objects.update(name=name, market=market,
                                     assets=assets,
                                     )

            return portfo
        else:
            pass
```

and at the end it is my error:

TypeError at /market/update/1
put() got an unexpected keyword argument 'id'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer by my self,because I needed to use id for get obj so I used request.data that is body's data  of object include obj's id and added query-set method for getting the class objs

```
    class PortfolioUpdateView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    serializer_class = PortfolioSerializer

    def get_queryset(self):
        portfolio = Portfolio.objects.all()
        return portfolio

    def put(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
        data = Portfolio.objects.get(id=request.data['id'])
        update_portfolio = Portfolio.objects.update(name=data['name']
                                                    , market=Market.objects.get(pk=int(request.POST.get('market', ''))))

        update_portfolio.save()
        for asset in data['assets']:
            asset_obj = Assets.objects.update(asset_name=asset['asset_name'])
            update_portfolio.assets.add(asset_obj)

        serializer = PortfolioSerializer(update_portfolio)
        return Response(serializer.data)
```

And this is the URL

```
   router.register("update", PortfolioUpdateView, basename="update")
```